# How to check for outliers and leverage values in SPSS when conducting a multinomial logistic regression?

Tags: spss, outliers, multinomial-logit, leverage

I am conducting a multinomial logistic regression in SPSS. I want to check for the presence of outliers and high leverage values. How do I do that in SPSS?

Answer (score 1):

The LOGISTIC REGRESSION procedure provides leverages for binary response models, but none  of the SPSS procedures that will fit multinomial logistic models provide leverage statistics for them.

Nothing fancy is provided in the way of residuals statistics either. It is possible to save actual category probabilities in the NOMREG (Multinomial Logistic Regression) procedure. Small predicted probabilities for the actually occurring group would be indicative of badly mis-predicting cases.